# Sorting algorithm has problems when a negative number is inputted

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, terminal

I'm trying to write code in C that sorts n numbers from least to greatest. It works fine when all the numbers are positive but it returns 0 at the first index when I put a negative number.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mySort.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data[100000]; /* Array of ints to sort */
    int nDataItems;
    if (argc > 1) {
        nDataItems = argc;
        for (int i = 0; i < nDataItems; i++)
            data[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
    } else {
        nDataItems = 4;
        data[0] = 10;
        data[1] = 20;
        data[2] = 30;
        data[3] = 40;
    }
     
    mySort(data, nDataItems);

    for (int i = 0; i < nDataItems - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) {
            printf("Sorting error at index %d \n", nDataItems);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
  
    printf("Printing Array: \n");

    for (int i = 1; i < nDataItems; i++)
        printf("%d \n", data[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the code for the sorting:

```
void mySort(int d[], unsigned int n)
{
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         x = i - 1;
         y = d[i];
         while (x >= 0 && d[x] > y) {
             d[x+1] = d[x];
             x--;
        }
        d[x + 1] = y;
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the code is taking in negative numbers and converting it to 0. I'm suspecting the issue is with `atoi` but not certain.  [Here is a picture of the terminal when I try testing it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4gqN.png):

```
C:\Users\danes\Desktop\COE428\lab1›testSort2 2 76 33 11 9
Printing Array
2
9
11
33
76

C:\Users\danes\Desktop\COE428\lab1> testSort2 -5 11 29 15 2
Printing Array
0
2
11
15
29
```

Comment: @Shawn: Do you? Looks like most of them are okay. I see one where it's probably unintended (the loop reading in items from the command line should start from 1; as is, it'll try to parse an integer from the program's name), but that's it. All the others are bounded properly to `- 1` from a bound when it uses the index + 1 for indexing or the like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you mind explaining how I can fix it?

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<nDataItems; i++)` - you aren't printing `data[0]`. That's where the `-1` is hiding.

Comment: `argc` will always be at least 1 since `argv[0]` is the name of the program being run. The loop that reads the arguments is incorrect.  `nDataItems = argc - 1;` and `data[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);` will fix that. If you're unsure about why something is happening then test or debug it. Think `atoi` is returning the wrong value then print out the value in the array after that step is done and before the sort changes/breaks it. https://godbolt.org/z/n34sb6d3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in the code:

- you copy the command line arguments from `argv[0]` to `argv[argc - 1]`, which is incorrect as `argv[0]` is the name of the program, not a command line argument.  You get one more entry in the array than there are arguments and this initial entry is `0` as the name of the program starts with a letter.
- you output the array from `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`, so you skip the lowest element after the sort.

If all arguments are positive, the extra `0` sorts to the lowest position and is skipped on output, hiding the problem, but if there is at least one negative number, the `0` appears in the output and the lowest number is missing as observed in the second example.

A typical case of two bugs cancelling each other, but not always.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mySort.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data[100000]; /* Array of ints to sort */
    int nDataItems;
    if (argc > 1) {
        nDataItems = argc - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < nDataItems; i++)
            data[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    } else {
        nDataItems = 4;
        data[0] = 10;
        data[1] = 20;
        data[2] = 30;
        data[3] = 40;
    }
     
    mySort(data, nDataItems);

    for (int i = 0; i < nDataItems - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) {
            printf("Sorting error at index %d\n", nDataItems);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
  
    printf("Printing Array:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nDataItems; i++)
        printf("%d \n", data[i]);

    return 0;
}

void mySort(int d[], unsigned int n)
{
    // perform insertion sort
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
         int y = d[i];
         for (int x = i; x > 0 && d[x - 1] > y; x--) {
             d[x] = d[x - 1];
        }
        d[x] = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! Works now!